Movie where both dad and son die but come back to life
I'm trying to identify a movie that I watched years ago as a kid. My memory of this movie is vague and incomplete, and I've been searching the internet to no avail. It's driving me absolutely crazy. Here's what I remember. 
It takes place in the old west (ish) of the United States (I think). There are two main characters: a young woman and a young man . I think I remember that the girl's name is Cheyenne (maybe spelled differently?), but I forget the boy's name. The boy's father had died and briefly came back to life on his deathbed to say his last words before dying again, and no one knew how. There was a horse race towards the end of the movie, and the boy died after his horse fell on him or something like that. Cheyenne was distraught, but the boy then came back to life, as his father did before, and then stayed alive. Everyone was happy. The end. 
I remember liking this movie, and wouldn't mind seeing it again, but I can't for the life of me figure out what movie it is. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you! =]
Edit: Here's some additional information. I watched this movie sometime either in the late 90's or early 00's. It was either featured on TV or rented by my parents. The movie probably wasn't any older than 15 or 20 years, maybe newer, and it was not animated. 

Sounds like Ron Howard's Far And Away from 1992 with Tom Cruise and Nicole Kidman that takes place in 1890s America. From IMDb:  

Joseph Donnelly, a young Irish man facing property eviction after his father's death, decides to take revenge on Daniel Christie, his landlord. In an attempt to kill Christie, however, he is injured and sentenced to a duel with Christie's arrogant manager, Stephen Chase. Meanwhile, Shannon, Daniel's daughter, is growing dissatisfied with the traditional views of her parents' generation and longs to be modern. She makes her plans to leave for the U.S., and with her help, Joseph is able to escape.

In the beginning of the movie, Joseph's father dies but briefly comes back to life to tell him his last words. In the end of the movie, Joseph is crushed by a horse and, like his father, says that he's dying, but then comes back to life and stays alive. Here's the trailer:



